# ¿Cómo hacer que un atributo de un objeto se incremente y como acceder a dicho atributo desde otro script de otro objeto en Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, atributos, autoincremento

estoy haciendo un simple juego de naves el cual se basa en disparar ovnis y estos te den 100 puntos, es juego pequeño. Soy principiante en Unity, pero tengo entendido que maneja C# como lenguaje y es programación orientado a objetos por lo que yo pienso que los puntos tienen que ser como un atributo del objeto enemigo(ovnis), el cual me genere cierta cantidad de puntos como lo pueden ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no me incrementa el valor de los puntos se que solo 100 pero no aumenta en dicho valor es decir 200...300...etc.

Y no sé que hacer ya que quiero hacer a valor de dicho valor en otro script el cual me escriba el valor del puntaje por pantalla pero no me deja ya que me dice que dicho atributo es nulo aunque el motor me muestra que es 0 no es NULL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad quiero que hasta el momento quiero arreglar el auto incrementable de los puntos y ver eso por consola desde el segundo script.

Answer (score 0):

en el script del enemigo implementa lo siguiente:

```
puntaje puntos;

void start()
{
  puntos =  GameObject.Find("nombre del objeto que tenga el script de puntaje").GetComponent<puntaje>();


}

y en 

public void OnCollision2D(Collision2D collision)
{
puntos.record +=100;
puntos.valorpuntaje.text = puntos.record.toString();
Destroy(gameobject);
}
```

y olvidate en tener los puntos en el enemigo, los puntos los tienes que guardar en algun objeto que siempre este activo no se si me explico

de esta forma los puntos los guardas en el script puntaje en la variable record y con el texto valorpuntaje muestras el valor de record que seria tus puntos, espero haberme explicado